# Performance of split() over substr()

Tags: javascript, performance

In a tutorial for building a CSS selector engine in JavaScript (visible for Tuts+ members [here](http://tutsplus.com/tutorial/building-a-simple-css-selector-engine/)) the author uses the following code to remove everything in a string before the hash character:

```
// sel = "div#main li"
if (sel.indexOf("#") > 0) {
    sel = sel.split("#");
    sel = "#" + sel[sel.length -1];
}
```

While I'm a JavaScript beginner, I'm not a beginner programmer. And this seem such a overwhelming operation, like killing an ant with a cannon. I'd use something like:

```
sel.substr(sel.indexOf("#"));
```

Maybe even not enclosed with the if statement which already uses `indexof()`. So, as the author even wrote a book on JavaScript, there must be some secret that I'm not aware of: are there any advantages of using the former code? On performance maybe?

Comment: I would be stunned if the overhead of `split()` were less than what you suggest. Sadly, there are a lot of terrible JavaScript books and tutorials out there. (I don't know anything about your tutorial of course, so this may just be an anomaly, or a result of some cargo cult "tradition".)

Comment: Oh also: you can use [this website](http://jsperf.com) to do some simple comparative performance tests.

Comment: Go ahead and profile both ways on *your* specific page where you want to use it. There's no hard-and-fast rule which would hold for every situation.

Comment: And I would never use substr but instead use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or slice - I started using JS when substr was not cross browser

Comment: Thanks @Pointy . At the end I really think this tutorial was poorly planed, I see a lot of other inconsistencies in it. The subject picked me up, but later I realize it has nothing "new". One of those "if I knew it was that simple I'd have done it better"…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's usually a wide variation of performance between different implementations, so testing would be needed. But if performance is really a consideration, I would bet that `.split()` is slower.

> *"Maybe even not enclosed with the if statement..."*

But I would say that you should't have it inline as you do. The `.indexOf()` will return `-1` if no match is found, which will cause `.substr` to give you the last character of the string.

```
var sel = 'tester';
sel.substr(sel.indexOf("#")); // "r"
```

So keep the `if` statement...

```
var sel = 'tester',
    idx = sel.indexOf("#"),
    sub;

if( idx !== -1 ) {
    sub = sel.substr("#");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the tutorial is trying to do, but `sel="div#main li#first"` is valid CSS and their code would return `#first` and `sel.substr(sel.indexOf("#"));` would return `#main li#first`.  I'm guessing, but that could work in a loop where you work backwards through the CSS selectors.

Answer (score -2):

[Real life CSS selector engines](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js) use regular expressions for everything and this seems to be the best way. The language provides us with a dedicated powerful tool for string manipulations, so why not to use it. In your case:

```
 sub = sel.replace(/^.+?#/, "#")
```

does the job fast and without extra clutter.

Performance? In javascript we usually don't care much, because our applications are not time-critical. Nobody cares if it takes 0.1 or 0.01 sec to validate a form or to fade in a div.